# How does the CLR know if a static field has already been initialized?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, cil, static-initialization

There is one thing I have been always been wondering about `static fields` / `constructors`.

The `static class` initialized the first time one of it's fields is referenced, that is easy.

But how does the CLR know that it is the first time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CLR maintains a table of all types that have been loaded and their initialization status. If `A` is using a static field of `B` then the CLR knows that `A` is using `B` and while initializing `A` it will also initialize `B`. So the check if dependencies are initialized is not performed on each access. It is ensured though dependency graph of the types.

If you are interested in the implementation details you can have a look at the `IsClassInitialized` method of the `DomainLocalModule` in [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/43b39a73cbf832ec13ec29ed356cb75834e7a8d7/src/vm/appdomain.hpp#L427) and its [usage](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/methodtable.cpp#L3689) when instances of classes are created.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes, thanks very much. Though I have to admit, this seems expensive to check everytime when accessing a field (in a comparison to C++ for example)

Comment: To be clear this check is no performed on each access to the class. The class loading state is checked when the using class is loaded. If your Class A uses a static property of B.foo then when A is used its dependencies are checked. So when A is initialized B will be initialized too. the access to B.foo does not yield such checks.

Comment: I have done some edits to the answer to make it more clear when this check happens.

Answer (score 2):

> The `static class` initialized the first time one of it's fields is referenced, that is easy.

No, it's not that simple. Ignoring method calls, a `static` class has to be initialized just before one of its fields is accessed for the first time, if it's not marked `beforefieldinit`. If it is marked `beforefieldinit`, it can be initialized earlier than that. (Jon Skeet has [an article with lots more information about `beforefieldinit`](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx).)

How does this affect when is class initialization checked? Since CLR uses JIT compilation, it checks for class initialization when JIT compiling the method. If the class is marked `beforefieldinit` and it hasn't been initialized yet, the JIT compiler initializes it right away. It then actually compiles the method, where it can assume that the class has been initialized already, so no checks are necessary.

Without `beforefieldinit`, if the class hasn't been initialized yet, the JIT compiler has to emit code that checks for initialization before every potential first field access. But if the class is already initialized and another method is being JIT compiled, the JIT compiler doesn't have to emit the checks there anymore.

This can have negative effect on performance in some cases. From the above it's clear that to protect against this, you need to make sure the problematic classes are marked `beforefieldinit`. And the way to do that from C# is to not have a `static` constructor, use only `static` field initializers.

Comment: Interesting. I guess this would be especially problematc if the potential first field Access is strewn wildly over the entire solution and heavily dependent on external Input. Definitely thank you for the in-depth-answer.